# How can I create a dynamic range for a pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to write a macro that creates a pivot table on a new sheet based on data from a master spreadsheet. How can I adjust my code to do this?

I've gotten the code to work with static data but whenever the data is dynamic, the macro does not work. I believe the issue is with the first line starting with "srcData = ". The line below, which is commented out, works without any issues.

```
Option Explicit

Dim pivotSht As Worksheet
Dim dataSht As Worksheet
Dim pCache As PivotCache
Dim pTable As PivotTable
Dim srcData As String
Dim pRange As Range
Dim lastR As Long
Dim lastC As Long

Public Sub buildPivot()

Set dataSht = Worksheets("OOB")

'Defines data range in "OOB" sheet
With dataSht
    lastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    lastC = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set pRange = .Range(.Cells(1, "D1"), Cells(lastR, lastC))
End With

Sheets("OOB").Activate
srcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & pRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
'srcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("D1:U714").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Delete old "PivotTable" worksheet if it exists
On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete

'Create new sheet and name it "PivotTable"
Set pivotSht = Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"

'Set location of pivot table
startPvt = pivotSht.Name & "!" & pivotSht.Range("A3").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Define pivot cache
Set pCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=srcData)

'Creates pivot table from pivot cache
Set pTable = pCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    tabledestination:=startPvt, _
    TableName:="Open Order Book Table")

End Sub

The expected output is a pivot table using all data as the source, even with changing data.
```

Comment: You're missing a period in front of the second `Cells` in the `Set pRange = ...` line.

Comment: Side note: tips to create "dynamic" pivot tables: i) create the pivot table from a table, ii) create the pivot table using PowerQuery -> PowerPivot.

Comment: I've added the period, also forgot to add a variable: dim startPvt as String has been added. I am now getting an error message on the set pRange line stating "run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: You can't have `D1` as a column argument there...

Comment: Make it easier... write a named ranged with this formula: `=OFFSET(A1,0,0,COUNTA(A:A),COUNTA(1:1))` use the sheet reference and you will have a dynamic range for your pivot table, then call that range on your source for the pivot table and thats all.

Comment: I changed the D1 to "4" and the code now works.